# How can I downgrade phpbb 3.1 to phpbb 3.0?

Tags: phpbb

I did an install of phpbb through softaculous in my cPanel and it automatically installed the latest version of phpbb. I don't want to use phpbb 3.1 however because the styling files that I have created are not compatible with it. Is there any way I can downgrade to phpbb 3.0 easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot downgrade phpBB to a lower version, because the database will have been upgraded to the 3.1 structure. The only way you could downgrade is by restoring the old files (php files, etc.) and the old 3.0 database.